# Adding a small perturbation to a uniform density region

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, newtonian-gravity, perturbation-theory

Suppose some region with uniform mass density $\rho$. Suppose a sphere with radius $R$ (can vary with time) and uniform density $\rho(1+\delta)$, $|\delta| \ll 1$ is placed in this region ($\delta = \delta(t)$). Using Newtonian gravity, we get an equation for the radius of the sphere (ignoring pressure)
$$
\frac{\ddot{R}}{R} = -\frac{4\pi G\rho}{3}\delta(t)
$$

A result immediately follows that if $\delta > 0$, the sphere contracts, and if $\delta < 0$ the sphere expands. Why, physically, an expanding sphere makes sense if the density of the sphere is less than the uniform density of the region it is in?

**EDIT**
Assume the region infinitely big, with uniform density, and suppose the sphere is at the origin. For a point on the sphere, $\vec{r} = R\hat{r}$. From Gauss's law, that point experiences only the gravitational field from mass inside the sphere, that is $\Delta M = \delta\rho$. Assuming the sphere exerts no pressure, we get that
$$
\ddot{R} = -\frac{G\Delta M}{R^2} = -\frac{G\delta\rho}{R^2}\frac{4\pi R^3}{3} = -\frac{4\pi G\rho R}{3}\delta
$$

Comment: Please can you show how you have done your calculation, and what assumptions you are making?

Comment: You are correct - done.

Comment: The force on the test particle should be proportional to $M$ not $\Delta M$. You must instead be calculating the change upon applying the perturbation which is different. Alternatively you might have pressure that balanced before but not after.